# How to construct a Where clause for an EntitySet

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Suppose I have two tables connected with a foreign key constraint. Consider the following code:

```
using(var dc = TestDataContext())
{
    IQueryable<ParentTable> query = dc.ParentTable;  
    query = query.Where(t => t.ChildTable.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("#")).Any());
    Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
}
```

If I needed to extend the `Where` clause on some conditions, I would simply chain `Where` clauses:

```
if(...)
    query = query.Where(...);
...
```

In fact it would be added to original `Where` clause through `AND` statement in sql.

Now imagine, I need to dynamically construct the `Where` clause on the `ChildTable` within the `ParentTable` `Where` clause...

I tryed to do this:

```
using(var dc = TestDataContext())
{
    IQueryable<ParentTable> query = dc.ParentTable;  

    //here specify the necessary condition 
    Func<ChildTable, bool> where;
    if(...)
        where = c => c.Name.StartsWith("#");
    else ...

    query = query.Where(t => t.ChildTable.Any(where));
    Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
}
```

However it throws the `NotSupportedException`, saying it could not properly convert the `where` `Func` specified for `Any` into sql.

I thought I could specify `Expression<Func<ChildTable, bool>>`, but `t.ChildTable` is `EntitySet<ChildTable>` so it does not implement `IQueryable<T>`...so a custom `Func<>` cannot be translated into sql properly.

Is there a way to achieve this goal except simply rewriting the whole statement each time:

```
1. query = query.Where(t => t.ChildTable.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("#")).Any());

2. query = query.Where(t => t.ChildTable.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("#") && ...).Any()));
```

...

Answer (score 0):

In cases where I need a dynamic where clause, I like to use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Translating the example on that site to your question gives the following code. You might need to dick about with `.AsExpandable()` if you're using EF, see the link for more info.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ParentTable>();
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.ChildTable.Any(c => c.Name.StartsWith("#"));

var keywords = "search terms go here";
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
  var temp = keyword;
  predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.ChildTable.Any(c => c.Name.Contains(temp));
}

using(var dc = TestDataContext())
{
  Console.WriteLine(dc.ParentTable.Where(predicate).Count());
}
```